# MYSQL ORDER, JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, order

Есть 2 таблицы:

```js
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_item_division` (
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `division_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  KEY `division_id` (`division_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `shop_item_division`
ADD CONSTRAINT `shop_item_division_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `shop_items` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_items_order` (
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `division_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sort` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `item_id` (`item_id`,`division_id`),
  KEY `division_id` (`division_id`),
  KEY `sort` (`sort`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `shop_items_order`
ADD CONSTRAINT `shop_items_order_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `shop_item_division` (`item_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `shop_items_order_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`division_id`) REFERENCES `shop_item_division` (`division_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

```html
SELECT shop_item_division.item_id 
FROM shop_items_order
RIGTH JOIN shop_item_division ON shop_item_division.division_id = shop_items_order.division_id AND shop_item_division.item_id = shop_items_order.item_id 
WHERE shop_item_division.division_id = 103 ORDER BY shop_items_order.sort
```

Выдает:

```js
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: shop_items_order
         type: ref
possible_keys: item_id,division_id
          key: division_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: shop_item_division
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: item_id,division_id
          key: item_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: shop_items_order.item_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Как реализовать выборку item_id и сортировку по sort из второй таблицы, используя индекс, НО! во второй таблице может не быть результатов, тогда сортирувтся как попало. Т.Е. в shop_items_order не для всех division_id есть строки

Comment: но если в shop_items_order нет записи, то откуда брать порядок сортировки, в каком порядке должны быть отсутствующие там записи. И что то мне подсказывает, что использовать индекс для сортировки не получится

Comment: Как тогда реализовать? Есть таблица соответствия раздела и товара, по id раздела получаем список товаров. Далее не для всех разделов установлена сортировка - в некоторых она не важна, как сделать сортировку для всех, имеющих записи?

Comment: Так сейчас у вас и сортируются все у которых есть записи

Comment: Необходимо использование индекса!

Comment: Но это невозможно ! Во первых оптимизатор MySQL крайне редко использует индексы для сортировки. Во вторых оптимизатор ни в одной БД не может использовать один индекс для join и другой для сортировки (а связь таблиц по ключу, в который поле order не входит). В третьих order by применяется (любой СУБД) ко всей выборке в целом, а в целой выборке есть записи, которых нет ни в одном индексе